# 'Text' does not contain a definition for 'text'

Tags: unity, c#

Not sure why '.text' is not in the Text class. The line with the comment next to it is the compile error.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

using Debug = UnityEngine.Debug;

public class TextTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    int n;
    public Text myText;
    public void triggerText()
    {
        n++;
        myText.text = "Button clicked " + n + " times"; //<- Error on this line
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not reproduce the problem. The very same script compiles perfectly fine for me if added to my test project.

Comment: Can you hover the `myText` variable in your IDE, and confirm what fully-qualified type name the compiler has resolved it to?

Comment: [This existing answer](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1340078/type-text-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-text.html) suggests that this error can occur if you've created your own type named `Text` in your project, which by default will take precedence over one you've referenced with `using`. Does the problem go away if you qualify your type name as `public UnityEngine.UI.Text myText;`?